# What is the alternative way for configuring tomcat context file with <Loader delegate = true />

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, tomcat7, tomcat8

I'm working on a web application recently I faced with an issue of ClassCastException, found that same class been loaded by two different ClassLoaders. I'm not able to reproduce this issue in cluster. I'm facing this issue only in the Local environment. I configured the Tomcat Context.xml with `<Loader delegate =true />`
This solves my ClassCastException issue with proper ClassLoading mechanism as mentioned  [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html). Now since it is already working fine in the Cluster I dont want to make changes in the context.xml. So is there any alternative way.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Tomcat documentation,

"A Loader element MAY be nested inside a Context component. If it is not included, a default Loader configuration will be created automatically."

So, you can do this in server.xml without changing the Context.xml file.

```
        <Context path="" docBase="" debug="0">
            <Loader delegate="true"/>
        </Context>
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way to configure delegation is via a `Loader` element nested inside a `Context` element.

Answer (score 0):

The standard implementation of Loader is org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader. It supports the attribute loaderClass.

Custom implementations must extend org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase

@see
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/loader.html